# Ionic label click not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Sometimes I don't understand why Ionic is so inflexible. I have an input and a label stacked on to each other:

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label stacked (click)="labelClick($event)" [innerHTML]="htmlString"></ion-label>
<ion-input  ></ion-input>
```

And the `labelClick()` function just ins't firing no matter what.

Is there something I can do so that clicking on the LABEL fires the function? Without changing the appearance/used components.

Here is a stackblitz with this code demonstrating that it doesn't work:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5yreac?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: Can you share what is your use case and what you are trying to achieve? Ionic is pretty flexible its just nuanced sometimes. So seems like you are going some "edge case" and that's where you may feel this way.

Comment: When the label is clicked I need to check in the labelClick() method whether a link was clicked (via event.target). If it has been clicked, I should show an explanation for the link as a tooltip. However the tooltip shouldn't show up if any other part of the label is clicked.

Comment: and so why you want to use ion-input? sorry your context is still fuzzy, what you described can be achieved differently but I see you are using ion-input - does that mean you allow user to input arbitrary text with possibly links?

Comment: So the label is for a question and the question can have some explainable words, which is why I need to show the tooltips. But the input is for the answer to the question which has to be written in plain text. Basically in my real project changing this ion-label and ion-input will mean huge changes of the html and CSS code which will take days. Everything was fine until this requirement showed up and it's quite dissapointing that this not-that-advanced feature seems like it might be impossible.

Comment: i see let me try somethign

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a long time of investigation I found that this style was the problem (can be seen by inspecting the ion-label):

[image]

Therefore the solution is:

```
.item-input ion-label{
  pointer-events:all!important;
}
```

Together with:

```
 .item-cover{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by two ways as follows:
1] If you want ion-label and ion-input both in in same ion-item:
It has been observed that if ion-item with "ion-label" and "ion-input" together affects labels listeners due to "pointer-events" CSS. By default "pointer-events: none;" get added. Hence if you want click listener to be working then you need to override this style by adding below code:

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label class="clickEnableCls" stacked (click)="labelClick($event)" [innerHTML]="htmlString"></ion-label>
   <ion-input  ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

You need to add below class in your respective .scss file:

```
.clickEnableCls{
   pointer-events: visible !important;
}
```

2] It is possible by having ion-label and ion-input in two different ion-item as follows:

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label stacked (click)="labelClick($event)" [innerHTML]="htmlString"></ion-label>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-input  ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Sorry, never mind, I'm accepting my own answer as the correct one as it was the first one.

Answer (score 1):

So in your case the issue is that ion-input is "taking over" with its input listener and your link related (click) listener is no longer "heard".

I would try using this approach: use ionic cards (or grid) or separare divs to clearly divide user input area and your question text / string.

Here is the stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-9gz5ok

Comment: But I don't think the inputs listener takes over. That would mean that I could attach the listener to the input and the listener function would be triggered when I click on the label. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-g9uzpx?file=pages/home/home.html

Comment: I don't understand how Ionic has made the label just un-event-attachable, how is this even possible

Comment: The cards won't work as they change the layout dramatically

Comment: OK let me try one more thing:)

Comment: so you need to keep it as a list?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it has to be ion-item

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to use ion-items with click handlers in an ion-list in an ion-menu.
My template looks like:

```
<ion-menu>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item button (click)="myFunc()">A Clickable Menu Item</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-menu>
```

In my instance the offending style was:

```
.menu-content-open { pointer-events: none; }
```

My solution and I think a rather simple and flexible solution was to add the following global style:

```
ion-item[button] {
    pointer-events: initial !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into this too with Ionic 4.11.0.

This bit from http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20190920-HyperlinksInIonicCheckboxLabels.html helped me. It will still receive the full click events for ion-label, but `<a>` tags get a higher z-index, thus clicked first:

```
/* Ionic 4 */
.ion-activatable {
  ion-label {
    a {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 10;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
/* Ionic 5 */
.item-input ion-label {
   position: absolute;
}
```